# What is the normality test for binary data?

Tags: normality-assumption

While most of the tests for normality help for continous variables, is there a way to test the normality assumptions for binary variables.

From what i've read on wiki, the K-S test can be applied for continous variables. How do we perform normality tests for binary (or even categorical variables)?

Comment: vote to close.  (but I'm below 500r)

Answer (score 13):

There is no such thing as normality of categorical variable. Normal distribution is a continuous distribution so in assumption don't cover categorical output.

Comment: Ok, let me correct my question. How do you know if a binary variable follows the binomial distribution?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test . Talking as a moderator now: so can you please make a new, good question? You'll get a better answer and the wiki spirit of this site will be held.

Comment: Sure. Let me do that.